# Expandable ListView get group child count - onClick

Tags: android, listview

I am using an expandable listview in Navigation Drawer. Now the items in this list are fetched from a webservice - along with the children.

Based on the login type some users only see part of the Navigation drawer. So I have some items with 0 children and I need to detect this condition so that I can redirect on header click to a different page.

Here is my scenario:

I want to get the number of children in a group when the header is clicked. Is this even possible?

So far I have tried this, but the result are not proper:

```
 @Override
    public void onDrawerHeaderSelected(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, long id) {

        switch (groupPosition) {
            case 1:
                if (parent.getChildCount() == 0)
                    displayFragment(groupPosition);
                break;
            case 2:
                if (parent.getChildCount() == 0)
                    displayFragment(groupPosition);
                break;
            default:
                displayFragment(groupPosition);
        }


    }
```

`parent.getChildCount()` seems to give me a total nmber of visible children.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. I have an ExpandableListView in which I show the number of children on each Group header.

Comment: I use [getChildrenCount()](http://developer.android.com/intl/in/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListAdapter.html#getChildrenCount(int))

Comment: getChildren count is available in the Adapter not in the implementing class however.

Comment: Yes, then it becomes a property of your group.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use the Adapter.

```
ExpandableListAdapter adapter = parent.getExpandableListAdapter()
```

and trough adapter you can access `getChildrenCount` and `getGroupCount()`

Answer (score 5):

Use `setOnGroupClickListener` and in `onGroupClick` check your condition using the list of data that you already have and display fragment and return true.

To find group child count - 
`adapter.getChildrenCount(groupPosition)`

Comment: The above snippet is that of `GroupOnClickListener` - can you shed more light on how can I find the number of children in the code I have posted?